# ESRI JSAPI: How to use GMap3 as 1st layer when using gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com?

Tags: google-maps, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

This question relates to ESRI JSAPI and Google Maps V3 integration...

I've put together this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/br4pk/1/ which demonstrates a mismatch between the LOD of the map and gmaps.GoogleMapsLayer instance.  The map operates great until you introduce layers which specify an `lod[0]` with a `level:0`.  I believe this is because the gmaps layer `lod[0]` looks like this:

```
{
    "level": 1, 
    "resolution": 78271.5169639999, 
    "scale": 295828763.795777
}
```

and the map lod[0] like this:

```
{
    "level": 0, 
    "resolution": 78271.5169639999, 
    "scale": 295828763.795777
}
```

Should the map lod contain a level:0 when the basemap does not specify a level:0 lod?
What is the solution to getting this to work with other layers which do specify a level:0?

I did find some success in modifying the lods of the gmap by adding a level 0 detail, and perhaps that is the answer (to modify http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/gmapslayer/1.0/src/gmapslayer.js):

```
    { "level": 0, "resolution": 156543.033928, "scale": 591657527.591555 },
    { "level": 1, "resolution": 78271.5169639999, "scale": 295828763.795777 },
    { "level": 2, "resolution": 39135.7584820001, "scale": 147914381.897889 },
    { "level": 3, "resolution": 19567.8792409999, "scale": 73957190.948944 },
    { "level": 4, "resolution": 9783.93962049996, "scale": 36978595.474472 },
    { "level": 5, "resolution": 4891.96981024998, "scale": 18489297.737236 },
    { "level": 6, "resolution": 2445.98490512499, "scale": 9244648.868618 },
    { "level": 7, "resolution": 1222.99245256249, "scale": 4622324.434309 },
    { "level": 8, "resolution": 611.49622628138, "scale": 2311162.217155 },
    { "level": 9, "resolution": 305.748113140558, "scale": 1155581.108577 },
    { "level": 10, "resolution": 152.874056570411, "scale": 577790.554289 },
    { "level": 11, "resolution": 76.4370282850732, "scale": 288895.277144 },
    { "level": 12, "resolution": 38.2185141425366, "scale": 144447.638572 },
    { "level": 13, "resolution": 19.1092570712683, "scale": 72223.819286 },
    { "level": 14, "resolution": 9.55462853563415, "scale": 36111.909643 },
    { "level": 15, "resolution": 4.77731426794937, "scale": 18055.954822 },
    { "level": 16, "resolution": 2.38865713397468, "scale": 9027.977411 },
    { "level": 17, "resolution": 1.19432856685505, "scale": 4513.988705 },
    { "level": 18, "resolution": 0.597164283559817, "scale": 2256.994353 },
    { "level": 19, "resolution": 0.298582141647617, "scale": 1128.497176 }
```

Comment: Seems when a basemap is added to an ESRI map the level is automatically set to zero.  The compressed function _639 contains logic which intentionally overwrites the level specified in the basemap.  This also happens when setting LOD via map constructor:

    map = new esri.Map("map", {
        extent: initExtent,
        lods: [{
            "level": 1,
            "resolution": 78271.5169639999,
            "scale": 295828763.795777
        }]
    });

    alert(dojo.toJson(map.__tileInfo.lods[0], true));

Comment: Qn: Should the map lod contain a level:0 when the basemap does not specify a level:0 lod?

Ans: Yes, apparently so since ESRI is explicitly overwriting the level.

Qn: What is the solution to getting this to work with other layers which do specify a level:0?

Ans: Explicitly set the lod on the map constructor and select a suitable extent.  This will resolve the issue.  With this change the google map can be properly overlayed by an ESRI tiles as shown on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/br4pk/3/.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the latest version of agsjs and setting the lods on the map directly.  You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/br4pk/4/